# Gamma-like distribution integral

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

Here I have an integral which is similar to gamma distribution,
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda x} \lambda^n x}{(n-1)!}dx
$$
and how to compute its integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts:

$\begin{aligned}   \int_0^{\infty} x e^{- \lambda x } \, \mathrm dx & =  -\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^{\infty} x \left(e^{- \lambda x }\right)' \, \mathrm dx  \\& = -\frac{1}{\lambda}x e^{-\lambda x}\bigg|_0^\infty + \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}\,  \mathrm dx  \\& = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}. \end{aligned}  $

So $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda x} \lambda^n x}{(n-1)!}\, \mathrm dx = \frac{\lambda^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}. $

Comment: yes but if you had $x^{10}$ instead of $x$ what would you do? 10 times by parts?

Comment: Well, that is! I try to construct a complicated gamma distribution and get confused. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your integral in the following form

$$\frac{\lambda^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}(\lambda x)e^{-\lambda x}d(\lambda x)}_{=\Gamma(2)=1}=\frac{\lambda^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}$$

Inside the integral you have a [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). In particular you have $\Gamma(2)=1!=1$